# Plotting Multiple Lines in GGplot with Different lines corresponding to a different year

Tags: r, ggplot2, aggregate

I am trying to use ggplot to plot multiple lines (categorized by years) for means for a categorical variable. I am stumped and have tried a variety of things but can't get exactly what I want. I have raw observations that have a year flag on each observation and a Loss value attached to them but here is a snapshot of me trying to group the mean losses by year/judicial orientation.

I want to aggregate all the Loss values by categorical variable level and then aggregate those further by the Year

My goal is this:

I want one graph that has a variable number of levels depending on variable (for JudicialOrientation I have 3 levels: Defense, Neutral, Plaintiff) so those would be the x values, I then want to have a line graph connecting the means between each 3 levels but I want multiple lines that represent 2006, 2007, 2008 etc.

So I would have different colored lines that correspond to a different year's MeanLoss value for that particular level. I hope this makes sense.

I am new to ggplot and I see some people use one line and others use multiple lines. I am ok with either approach.

An attempt so far:

```
ggplot() +geom_line(data=df1, aes(x=JudicialOrientation, y = MeanLoss, color=Year))
```

An example data frame with some dplyr code to obtain aggregate means:

```
df <-data.frame(Year=c("2006","2006","2006","2007","2007","2007","2008","2009","2010","2010","2009","2009"), 
           JudicialOrientation=c("Defense","Plaintiff","Plaintiff","Neutral","Defense","Plaintiff","Defense","Plaintiff","Neutral","Neutral","Plaintiff","Defense"),
           Loss = c(100000,100,2500,100000,25000,0,7500,5200, 900,100,0,50)
           )


df1 <- df%>% group_by(Year,JudicialOrientation) %>% summarise(MeanLoss =mean(Loss))
```

Let me know any tips you may have. Thanks!

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far?

Comment: I edited my post.This should give you a sample data frame you can work with. I want to aggregate the Loss column by JudicialOrientation and then plot a different line for each year in the data set to give aggregate meanLoss for each JudicialOrientation (on the x-axis preferably).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your saw the message after you run your code.

> geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

So adjusting the group aesthetic would give you this

```
ggplot(data = df1, aes(x = JudicialOrientation, y = MeanLoss, color=Year, group = Year)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

I added `geom_point` so you see that the values for e.g. 2008 are actually there. You wouldn't see them with only `geom_line`. Hope this helps.

---

You could even let `stat_summary` do the aggregation for you and use `df` directly.

Here is how

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = JudicialOrientation, y = Loss, color = Year, group = Year)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "line", fun.y = mean) +
  stat_summary(geom = "point", fun.y = mean)
```

Comment: This is very useful thanks. I did not know I needed a point when using categorical data to make it work properly.

Comment: @Coldchain9 You don't need the points actually - you simply cannot draw a line for  just one observation (that's what you brought you here, I guess).